# jQuery offset() is returning null for elements below the fold

Tags: javascript, jquery, lazy-loading

I suspect I'm misunderstanding something here, but I want to make sure that I'm not crazy. I have some JS that lazy loads some images. Here is a truncated version of what I'm doing:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
    self.image_holders = jQuery('.image-holder');
    jQuery.each(self.image_holders, function(i, placeholder){
        if ( jQuery(placeholder).offset() ){
            //compare offsets and load image if appropriate
        }
    });                
});
```

The matched elements that are below the fold or even just partially below the fold are returning `null` for `offset()`. What I am trying to accomplish is to load images that are within a certain threshold below the folder before the user scrolls to it. Is this expected behavior for jQuery? How can I get the value of the offsets before they appear above the fold?

Edit: To clarify these elements i need the offset for are NOT hidden or invisible, they are only 'below the fold'.

Answer (score 2):

Right from the [Docs](http://api.jquery.com/offset/):

> Note: jQuery does not support getting the offset coordinates of hidden elements or accounting for borders, margins, or padding set on
>   the body element.
>
> While it is possible to get the coordinates of elements with visibility:hidden set, display:none is excluded from the rendering
>   tree and thus has a position that is undefined.

Comment: The elements in question are not hidden, just out of view.

Comment: But it's not hidden, it's off screen. That means two very different things to me.